# How to pass global function value in query variable in React Apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, next.js

Hello I am trying to pass global function value in query variable using apollo react but not getting value.

```
import jwtDecode  from 'jwt-decode';
const tokenKey = 'token';


export function logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem(tokenKey);
}

export function getCurretUser (){
    try{
        const jwt = localStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
        return jwtDecode(jwt);
      }
      catch(ex) {
          return null;
      }
}

export function getJwt(){
    return  localStorage.getItem(tokenKey);
 }

export default {
    logout,
    getCurretUser,
    getJwt

}
```

I get global function value in render method but i want to pass it in out side render method.

```
    import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { css } from 'emotion';
import Head from 'next/head';

import { Button, Container, Input, H2, Grid, GridCell } from '../primitives';
import { Redirect } from '../components/Router';

import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import auth from '../components/authservice';



 class FavouriteJob extends React.Component {
//state = { loginUserId: '' };
static async getInitialProps({ auth }) {
    const getCurretUser  = await auth.getCurretUser(auth.getCurretUser);
    return getCurretUser;
}

onFavouriteJobDelete(jobid) {
    this.props
        .mutate({ variables: { jobid } })
        .then(() => this.props.data.refetch());
}

renderFavouriteJobs() {
    return this.props.data.getUserById.favourite.map(({ id, title }) => {
        return (
            <li key={id} className="collection-item">
                {title}
                <i
                    className="material-icons"
                    onClick={() => this.onFavouriteJobDelete(id)}
                >
                    Remove
                </i>
            </li>
        );
    });
}


render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        console.log(getCurretUser);
        if (this.props.data.loading) {
            return <div> Loading...</div>;
        }

        return (
            <Container>
                <div>
                    <ul className="collection">{this.renderFavouriteJobs()}</ul>
                </div>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const query = gql`
    query getUserById($id: ID!) {
        getUserById(id: $id) {
            username
            email
            phone
            favourite {
                id
                title
                description
                source
                logo
                suburb
                label
            }
        }
    }
`;

const mutation = gql`
    mutation removeFavouriteJob($jobid: ID!) {
        removeFavouriteJob(jobid: $jobid) {
            username
        }
    }
`;

export default graphql(mutation)(
    graphql(query, {
        options: props => ({ variables: { id: '5c73e07fef69a470c8785455' } }),
    })(FavouriteJob)
);
```

Anyone Please suggest possible solution to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: use react context api . this can help you to store global function value and then retrieve

Comment: Hello thanks for your quick help do you have any example code links?

Comment: refer this link https://coursework.vschool.io/token-auth-with-jwts-part-2-react-context/ .